# API can't handle "npm run generate" dynamic routes with Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, contentful, netlify

When running `npm run generate` the Contentful API fails regularly. I'm not sure if this is due to them not being able to handle the load or from my generate script for dynamic routes not being performant. The weird thing is it has worked fine up until a few days ago.

Generate function to build dynamic routes

```
generate: {
routes: async function() {
  const productModelNumbers = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "products"
  })

  const accessoryModelNumbers = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "accessories"
  })

  const categories = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "category"
  })

  const productRoutes = productModelNumbers.items.map(product => {
    return {
      route: `products/${product.fields.category.fields.slug}/${product.fields.modelNumber}`,
      payload: product
    }
  })

  const accessoryCategories = categories.items.map(category => {
    return {
      route: `accessories/${category.fields.slug}`,
      payload: category
    }
  })

  const accessoryRoutes = accessoryModelNumbers.items.map(accessory => {
    return {
      route: `accessories/${accessory.fields.category.fields.slug}/${accessory.fields.modelNumber}`,
      payload: accessory
    }
  })

  return [...productRoutes, ...accessoryRoutes, ...accessoryCategories]
}
}
```

The error
[image]

Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: it seems contenfull timeout for some reason. maybe it trying to fetch something from slow remote endpoint or its just something large that it cant process in time..

Comment: It's around 328 routes. But what's weird is it performs fine locally. Usually only when netlify runs npm run generate contentful times out. But its really inconsistent and hard for me to troubleshoot.